# HTML Range Getting Stuck Sometimes

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-input

As I slide the HTML range input, my mouse turns into the "not-allowed" cursor, and the sliding stops.

```css
.main__slider__input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__slider">
  <!-- <label for="slider-height">Height</label> -->
  <input id="slider-height" type="range" class="main__slider__input" />
  <!-- <label for="slider-width">Width</label> -->
  <input id="slider-width" type="range" class="main__slider__input" />
  <!-- <label for="slider-zoom">Zoom</label> -->
  <input id="slider-zoom" type="range" class="main__slider__input" />
</div>
```

At first, I thought the mouse was dragging on the HTML labels I had added to the inputs. However, when I commented those out, the problem persisted.

Here is a video demonstrating the problem.

[Range Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSCqd.gif)

I think the mouse is focusing on some whitespace around the input, and that is preventing it from sliding smoothly, how do I go about rectifying this problem.

Comment: I can reproduce the same behaviour on the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) of the "range" input so i believe that behaviour isnt caused by any of your custom code.

Comment: Thanks for that @FabianS. Is there any way we could get rid of that behavior though?

Comment: I can reproduce the same behavior but only when the mouse is not exactly positioned on the slider, it will behave like you want to drag the div. So no solution, just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

As reported by [Grumpy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232519/grumpy), this is caused by accidentally selecting element behind the slider.
So this can be fixed by disabling selection in the container with:

```
.container{
 -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
 -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
 user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
}
```